# IndexError: array index out of range (but index does exist?)

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

I've had out of range index error, however, it makes no sense to me why this would be the case. the offending code is as follows:

```
L = []
A = arr.array("i",[])
i=0

while i < 10:
  L.append(df.Title[i])
  A.append(len(df.Title[i]))
  i += 1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.bar(L,A)
fig.suptitle('Total Characters in a Stack Overflow Post Title with Outliers')
plt.xlabel('Title')
plt.ylabel('# of Characters')
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=10, rotation='vertical')
plt.plot

std = np.std(A)
mean = np.mean(A)

j=0
while j < 10:
  if A[j] > mean - 2 * std or A[j] < mean + 2 * std: #The error occurs on this line with A[j]
    A.pop(j)
    L.pop(j)
  j += 1
```

In terms of the relevant output, when numbers are appended to the array, the values read as follows:
0
1
2
3
4
5``
6
7
8
9

However when printing from j within the while loop, it only prints up to index 4 and then has the aforementioned array error. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: See what `A.pop(j)` does.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because  you are popping elements from A using “A.pop(j)”. This action reduce your array by one element on each iteration, so when j gets to 4 remaining array elements have been popped out.

Answer (score 1):

You are removing elements from the array you are iterating on. Meaning the lengths of `A`  and `L` before you start the last while loop are both 10, but every time your if statement is true, their length is decreased by 1. A crude, but easy way to bypass this is to define a new variable with the same values as `A`:

```py
j=0
B = A[:]
while j < 10:
  if B[j] > mean - 2 * std or B[j] < mean + 2 * std:
    A.pop(j)
    L.pop(j)
  j += 1
```

Comment: Better to decrease `j` by one when removing

Comment: And `while j < len(A)`

Comment: Thank you! this was very helpful, an oversight on my part.